# Custom Cursor to Text with AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, filter, cursor, autocompletetextview

I have created a custom view by extending AutoCompleteTextView (with a specialized function called setCursorAdapter). I am supplying a SimpleCursorAdapter and adding a FilterQueryProvider. I am using this for a list of numbers where I need the ability to search anywhere within the number for a match.

```
public void setCursorAdapter(final Uri uri, final String key) {

        Cursor c = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri,
                new String[] { "_id", key }, null, null, key);
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, c,
                new String[] { key }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });

        this.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                ((SimpleCursorAdapter) getAdapter()).getFilterQueryProvider()
                        .runQuery(s);

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {

            @Override
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                Cursor c = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri,
                        new String[] { "_id", key },
                        key + " LIKE '%" + constraint + "%'", null, key);
                return c;
            }
        });
        setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Everything is working perfectly, until I select the value from the drop down. The value that I receive in the EditText window: android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@...

How do I avoid this and get my (numeric) text displayed correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: SimpleCursorAdapter.converToString(cursor) -- I overrode this function to extract the value.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to use [public void setStringConversionColumn (int stringConversionColumn)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#setStringConversionColumn%28int%29)